# Did Brainiac ever appear in Lois and Clark?

Tags: dc, superman, lois-and-clark, brainiac

Did Brainiac ever appear in the Lois and Clark series in the '90s.  I do recall Mister Mxyzptlk appeared, and so did Zod and Luthor; but did Brainiac?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I can recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  He is not [credited on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106057/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast).  Nor do I remember him appearing on the show.  A [search on the Wikia](http://lois-and-clark-the-new-adventures-of-superman.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=brainiac) devoted the show turns up nothing about Brainiac either.

Comment: Long time for me to respond, thanks.